# ProcessBuilder Java launch successfully But Tomcat launch failed

Tags: java, tomcat, processbuilder

I run this method in normal java program (eclipse and cmd) successfully, but when I run this method in Tomcat 8.5.9, it shows error(Error: Could not find or load main class Main). Why that happened? Thanks for help.

```
public synchronized static String run(SourceCode sourceCode) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder java = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Main");
        File file = new File("C:\\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\\webapps\\onlineJudge\\data\\Piers\\1\\1483703529849");
        java = java.directory(file);
        java = java.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = java.start();
        List<String> list = java.command();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(process.getInputStream())) {
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Dir: C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\onlineJudge\data\Piers\1\148370352984
>
> File in Dir: Main.class, Main.java(code below)

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World.");
    }
}
```

PS:

**How I test:**

Copy this method to another normal Java Project and test. It shows (Hello World.).

**Something Wired**

After I post this question, I run Tomcat in **Eclipse**. Before, I run Tomcat in **cmd**(use startup command). When load the method(public synchronized static String run(SourceCode sourceCode)) it runs successfully! What happened?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the fully qualified name is `Main`?  What package is `Main` in?

Comment: Can you print content of C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\onlineJudge\data\Piers\1\1483703529849 ?

Comment: I update the question, could you please look at it?

Comment: does `Main.java` start with a `package <something>` line?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author.
I find that Tomcat changed my **classpath** for compling java! It uses its own **classpath** for security.